# Copy from one SQL Server database to another same database on other machine the data for specific dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have two identical databases (Schema) in two machines and I need to copy all the data from one database to the other from the date '20/09/2014' to the date '23/09/2014' how can I do it with SSMS? (or other tool maybe entity framework...)

Comment: If the databases are identical, why do you need to copy data from one to the other?

Comment: I meant identical schema...